# What is the meaning of "Are you into club today"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "Are you into club today"?

If someone (girl that she's not an English native speaker) asked me that question, then I believe that she meant to ask me if I'm into it, like if I want to go there, but I'm not sure if it's the correct meaning or it means that I'm inside the building.

Comment: It's an unlikely utterance, *whatever* the intended meaning. More natural would be *Are you **in*** (or ***at***) *the club today?* to ask if you are currently at the relevant location, or perhaps *Are you **into going to** the club today?* to ask whether you fancy going there later. Note the article - in such contexts we usually talk about ***the club*** (not just ***club***, but this is different with, say, *Are you at school today?*).

Comment: Unless this is slang, you might have misheard exactly what she said.  "Are you in *the* club" is more idiomatic, although the context is uncertain.

Comment: As presented, this question is unanswerable. If the speaker isn't a native Anglophone anyway, that just makes it more impossible for us to guess what she meant. All I can say is it's ***feasible*** for a native speaker to ask the cited text with the meaning *Do you want to go to [the] club today?*, but it's completely impossible to use ***into*** if the intended meaning is *Are you **at** the [club] today?* (which could itself be asking whether you're at the club *now*, OR whether you'll be going there later today).

Comment: Another possibility is that she intended to say "Are you into **clubbing** today?"  This would be very casual and idiomatic for a non-native speaker, but someone well-versed in English idiomatic use might know that "Are you into..." can mean "How do you feel about this..." and "clubbing" can mean going to a club or **going to multiple** clubs in one night.

Comment: I know already that she meant to ask me if I'm intrested  to go to club today. But I understood from your answers that for that meaning shehad to say "Are you into going to a club today?". Isn't it?

Comment: Did she say **tonight** or **today**?

Comment: Today, but I'm sure she meant tonight:)

Comment: You can ignore every other word in the question  :)

Comment: Why? What does it mean?) I really don't understand.

Comment: I mean, if you already understand what she means, despite what she says, then you don't have to worry about the words.

Comment: Ok, I understand you. But still I think that you noted something important that I didn't noticed. By the way if I want to ask her back: "Are you into speaking Spanish?" in meaning of "would you like to speak Spanish", is that correct?

Comment: to be **into** {something} means to be interested in it per se, or consuming it, or in doing it, or participating in an activity that involves it.  Are you into stamp collecting?  Are you into heavy metal (music)?  Are you into threesomes? Are you into wine?  Are you into baseball? Are you into clubbing?

Comment: If she is already a Spanish-speaker, to ask her if she is "into" it would be a little odd. To be **into** something is to have a special interest in it, to be an avid devotee, or to be a fan of it.  **She's really into Picasso**.  **He's really into Mayan art.** **They're really into The Rolling Stones.**

Comment: Here is a comic skit about the meaning of **into** by a New Zealand duo called *Flight of the Conchords*: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pY8jaGs7xJ0